# Subclassing UIImagePickerController for adding functionality

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, uiimagepickercontroller

So basically what i'm trying to do is, change the button of "take image", to a custom button of mine.
And when the user will change DeviceOrientation, the button will change according to the orientation.
I've already tried using the "overLay" property, but it seems not possible to change or move the "overLay" once its placed.
So I've decided to subclass the UIImagePickerController, but when i call it to present, the camera will not display at all!

Any help at understanding what is the problem will help... Thanks!!

This is the viewController Calling subclasses "UIImagePickerController":

```
@interface CameraViewController : UIViewController<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>
@interface CameraViewController ()
@property (nonatomic) pickerControllerMC *cameraPickerView;

self.cameraPickerView = [[pickerControllerMC alloc]initWithNibName:@"pickerControllerMC"       bundle:nil];
self.cameraPickerView.delegate = self;


// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
//create a new image picker instance
//set source to video!
self.cameraPickerView.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
//hide all controls
self.cameraPickerView.showsCameraControls = NO;
self.cameraPickerView.navigationBarHidden = YES;
self.cameraPickerView.toolbarHidden = YES;
//  self.delegate = self;
//make the video preview full size
self.cameraPickerView.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
self.cameraPickerView.cameraViewTransform =
CGAffineTransformScale(self.cameraPickerView.cameraViewTransform,
                       CAMERA_TRANSFORM_X,
                       CAMERA_TRANSFORM_Y);

//Getting WidthAnd hight
CGRect screen = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
//CGFloat widthInPixel = screen.size.width * scaleFactor;
//CGFloat heightInPixel = screen.size.height * scaleFactor;
int Width = screen.size.width;
int hight = screen.size.height;

[self presentViewController:self.cameraPickerView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

And this is The subclass:

```
 @interface pickerControllerMC : UIImagePickerController

 @implementation pickerControllerMC

    - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
    {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad
     {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIButton *buttonTakeImage = [UIButton
                        buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [buttonTakeImage setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CameraButton@2x"]     forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [buttonTakeImage addTarget:self action:@selector(takePictureClicked)     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self.view addSubview:self.overlay];
    [self.view addSubview:buttonTakeImage];


    //Adding orientation Notifications!
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector:        @selector(deviceOrientationDidChange:) name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object: nil];


    }
```

**Edit**

Ok my mistake was, i used "initWithNibName", so i got a white Nib screen every time.. all good.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sorry, you cannot subclass `UIImagePickerController`. From the docs:

> Important: The UIImagePickerController class supports portrait mode
>   only. This class is intended to be used as-is and does not support
>   subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not
>   be modified, with one exception. You can assign a custom view to the
>   cameraOverlayView property and use that view to present additional
>   information or manage the interactions between the camera interface
>   and your code.

However, you can have complete control over the picture taking UI.

- You can provide a `cameraOverlayView` to a `UIImagePickerController`.
- Avoid `UIImagePickerController` entirely by using `AVFoundation` classes to implement picture taking and your own `UIViewController` subclasses as the controller and views managing the UI and behavior. See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html.

Comment: First thanks for answering! What is that means exactly? My app is working perfectly with subclassing UIImagePickerController, Will it not be approved by apple? the problem with the camera overlay, Is ones you add an overLay, you can't move it around like i'm trying to do. i'm making the "TakePic" button, rotate around.

Comment: This means you shouldn't subclass `UIImagePicker`, rather, your customizations should be done in one of the methods recommended & supported by the SDK. If you do subclass `UIImagePicker`, depending on the view manipulations you make, you may get lucky and things will work but if they don't you're in unsupported territory.

Answer (score 0):

The `UIImagePickerController` can be subclassed to add properties to pass on to the `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` methods. I have done it without any issues. But one cannot play with it's methods or views.